# How can I pass variables in os.system?

Tags: python

I'm using this command to insert a variable :

```
`os.system("sudo insmod /home/hajer/final_module/module.ko src_ip=" +(R1.get()))`
```

and it works fine, but when I add some other variables it seems not working and I don't get the variables inserted.

```
os.system("sudo insmod /home/hajer/final_module/module.ko src_ip=" +(R1.get())+ "delay=" +(R2.get())+ "tcp_port=" +(R3.get()))
```

Comment: You might get better answers on StackOverflow or the Unix/Linux StackExchange, since this question isn't really specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing in these cases is just to print the string before using it so you can see if everything is correct.

```
command = "sudo insmod /home/hajer/final_module/module.ko src_ip=" +(R1.get())+ "delay=" +(R2.get())+ "tcp_port=" +(R3.get())
print(command)
os.system(command)
```

My guess is you're missing a space before the `delay` and `tcp_port` parameters.

```
command = "sudo insmod /home/hajer/final_module/module.ko src_ip=" +(R1.get())+ " delay=" +(R2.get())+ " tcp_port=" +(R3.get())
```

Then clean things up a bit:

```
command = "sudo insmod /home/hajer/final_module/module.ko src_ip=%s delay=%s tcp_port=%s" % (R1.get(), R2.get(), R3.get())
```

Also `os.system` is deprecated, you should use the `subprocess`module instead.

Comment: It works with the spaces :D thnx